# what is the easiest way to convert an array of bytes into a WPF bitmap

Tags: wpf, bitmap

Given an array of bytes, width, height, and a number of bits per pixel, what is the easiest way to create a WPF bitmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346378.aspx) as you know the width, height and BPP (which will map to PixelFormat). You can then write the bytes to the WriteableBitmap with WritePixels.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is already in a format listed by PixelFormats, you may directly use BitmapSource.Create().

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parameters you should keep in mind when creating a BitmapSource from scratch in WPF. In this case it looks like you are looking for a solution to a very specific image. In your situation I normally use a helper class that  encapsulate all these parameters and provide a simple approach to modify the pixels in a matrix way in case you need it. Finally, the way I use to obtain the bitmap is this:

```
BitmapSource.Create(Width, Height, DpiX, DpiY, PixelFormat, null, PixelData, Stride);
```

You can take a look at the entire class [here](https://csharpvault.com/blog/bitmapsource-helper/).